# Call a jar using perl and pass variables using STDIN

Tags: java, perl, jar, stdin

I am calling a jar via perl with the following command.

```
my $command = "$java_home/bin/java my_jar.jar ARG1 ARG2 ARG3";
my $result = `$command 2>&1;
```

However my JAR also expects arguments via STDIN.  I need to know how to pass those arguments.  I have tried passing them like normal arguments, and that didn't work.  I read on a forum that OPEN2 might work however after reading the documentation I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Any ideas on how to make this work would be great.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to send and receive data from the Java process, you need two-way communication. That's what `IPC::Open2` is designed to do. This allows you to create a dedicated pipe that renders `STDIN`/`STDOUT` unnecessary:

```
use IPC::Open2;

my $pid = open2( \*from_jar, \*to_jar, $command )
            or die "Could not open 2-way pipe: $!";

print to_jar, "Here is input\n";  # Pass in data

my $result = <from_jar>;          # Retrieve results
```

Also consider `IPC::Open3` to handle errors as well.

Comment: Thanks.  I am trying this... however when I try to run the command using open2 it seems to time out.  Any ideas what would cause this?

Comment: Nevermind... it seemed to be because I wasn't closing the Writer / Reader.  I fixed that but still not working.  Looking into it more.

Comment: @CameronJones : Is your Java process autoflushed? It could be buffering

Comment: Turns out what the jar was connecting to was shut off.  However, this part worked great.  Thank you.